# Why does if else statement not work the same way as else if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am trying to put a cards counting game together. There is multiple ways to write this piece of code, but the thing that makes me think is what the difference is between those to code samples? The first piece of code works fine, but the second gives me undefined.

```
  if (count > 0) {
       var betHigher = "Bet Higher";
       return betHigher;

   } else {
       count < 0;
       var holdbet = " hold ";
       return holdbet + "" + count;

   }
```

This gives me undefined. Why is that?

```
    if (count > 0) {
        var betHigher = "Bet higher";
        return betHigher;

    } else if (count < 0) {
        var holdbet = " hold";
        return holdbet;
    }

}
```

Comment: What if `count` is `0`? Your second code doesn't handle that case.

Comment: The first one works for count = 0

Comment: Your second example does not account for `count == 0` which is where you could have another `else if (count == 0)`. 
`else` handle all other situations where your `if`s are not met

Answer (score 1):

Your first example has an `else` which means "anytime count is not greater than 0"

Your second example does not, so if `count == 0` it would fail, which is why you get an error/undefined.

The `else` would handle that

```
if (count > 0) {
    var betHigher = "Bet higher";
    return betHigher;

} else if (count < 0) {
    var holdbet = " hold";
    return holdbet;
} else {
    // count is equal to 0 here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the count is 0, the second script will not pass any conditions, but the first code will run `else` block.

Answer (score 0):

In your first code example, `count < 0` is not being evaluated as an if statement, the result is calculated and then thrown out. It's roughly comparable to calling a function that returns a value but not using the value, both are just expressions to be evaluated. Only two conditions are actually being accounted for- `count > 0` and `count <= 0`.

The second code example does have this check, but only `count > 0` and `count < 0` are being accounted for. Note that when `count` is zero, no return statement is evaluated.